# Numpy, from a list of points, extract ones that have the same range of coordinates without for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I ran into some sort of numpy challenge.

I have a list of 3D points. For each point, the two first values are their coordinates on an image, and where the third is some sort of value associated with the point.

I want to put a 2D grid on the image, and build a array that contains the mean values of every point in a tile, and this for every tile.

I managed to make it using numpy but for optimisation (I don't really need it but now I'm curious to know if this is possible) I am looking for a way to remove the two last for loops in the code bellow, and get a full numpy version. I feel like there is something to do with np.mgrid but I didn't found how to exploit it yet. Can you help me?

```
import numpy as np

points_range = np.array([2, 5, 1])
points = np.random.random((100, 3))  # points[:, i] will be referred as x, y, z for i in 0, 1, 2
points *= points_range

x_steps = 10  # We will divide the points x space in 10 columns
y_steps = 15  # We will divide the points y space in 15 rows
x_step_size = points_range[0] / x_steps
y_step_size = points_range[1] / y_steps

# Do something with that ???
X, Y = np.mgrid[0:points_range[0]:x_step_size, 0:points_range[1]:y_step_size]

# Try the same with numpy: WORK
means = [[0 for _ in range(y_steps)] for _ in range(x_steps)]
for x_step_id in range(x_steps):
    for y_step_id in range(y_steps):
        # Compute the z average for every points in the tile [x_step_id, y_step_id]
        # -> get points that are inside this tile
        p = points[(points[:, 0] >= x_step_size * x_step_id) &
                   (points[:, 0] < x_step_size * (x_step_id + 1)) &
                   (points[:, 1] >= y_step_size * y_step_id) &
                   (points[:, 1] < y_step_size * (y_step_id + 1))]
        # -> get z average on these points
        mean_z = np.mean(p[:, 2])
        means[x_step_id][y_step_id] = 0 if np.isnan(mean_z) else mean_z
```

## SOLUTION

This code compare three versions with their duration.
The output of this code on my computer is (time in seconds, 10 million points, 15*15 grid):

```
Method for_loop_1 took 37.779709815979004
Method for_loop_2 took 14.891589879989624
Method for_plus_numpy took 16.47166681289673
Method full_numpy took 1.1438612937927246
```

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import time

points_range = np.array([2, 5, 1])
points = np.random.random((10000000, 3))  # points[:, i] will be referred as x, y, z for i in 0, 1, 2
points *= points_range

x_steps = 15  # We will divide the points x space in 10 columns
y_steps = 15  # We will divide the points y space in 15 rows
x_step_size = points_range[0] / x_steps
y_step_size = points_range[1] / y_steps


methods = []
def for_loop_1():
    start = time.time()
    means = [[0 for _ in range(y_steps)] for _ in range(x_steps)]
    n = np.zeros_like(means)
    for p in points:
        tile_x = int(p[0] // x_step_size)
        tile_y = int(p[1] // y_step_size)
        means[tile_x][tile_y] = (p[2] + n[tile_x][tile_y] * means[tile_x][tile_y]) / (n[tile_x][tile_y] + 1)
        n[tile_x][tile_y] += 1
    stop = time.time()
    return means, stop - start
methods.append(for_loop_1)

def for_loop_2():
    start = time.time()
    sums = np.zeros((x_steps, y_steps))
    counts = np.zeros((x_steps, y_steps))
    for point in points:
        tile_index_x = int(point[0] // x_step_size)
        tile_index_y = int(point[1] // y_step_size)
        sums[tile_index_x, tile_index_y] += point[2]
        counts[tile_index_x, tile_index_y] += 1
    means = np.where(counts > 0, sums / counts, 0)
    stop = time.time()
    return means, stop - start
methods.append(for_loop_2)

# Try the same with numpy
def for_plus_numpy():  # My method
    start = time.time()
    means = [[0 for _ in range(y_steps)] for _ in range(x_steps)]
    for x_step_id in range(x_steps):
        for y_step_id in range(y_steps):
            # Compute the z average for every points in the tile [x_step_id, y_step_id]
            # -> get points that are inside this tile
            p = points[(points[:, 0] >= x_step_size * x_step_id) &
                       (points[:, 0] < x_step_size * (x_step_id + 1)) &
                       (points[:, 1] >= y_step_size * y_step_id) &
                       (points[:, 1] < y_step_size * (y_step_id + 1))]
            # -> get z average on these points
            mean_z = np.mean(p[:, 2])
            means[x_step_id][y_step_id] = 0 if np.isnan(mean_z) else mean_z
    stop = time.time()
    return means, stop - start
methods.append(for_plus_numpy)


def full_numpy():
    start = time.time()
    edges = np.linspace(0, points_range[0], x_steps+1), np.linspace(0, points_range[1], y_steps+1)
    sums, _, _ = np.histogram2d(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], edges, weights=points[:, 2])
    counts, _, _ = np.histogram2d(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], edges)
    means = np.where(counts > 0, sums / counts, 0)
    stop = time.time()
    return means, stop - start
methods.append(full_numpy)


for method in methods:
    means, duration = method()
    print("Method ", method.__name__ + " took ", duration, sep="")
```

Comment: I may have misiniterpreted, but it looks to me like what you want is a convolution.

Comment: You also might consider OpenCV's `cv2.resize`, since what you're doing is very similar to reducing the size of an image.

Comment: What is `points_range`? It is not defined in your code.

Comment: @Oskar Hofmann right, solved

Comment: @Tim Roberts some sort of I would say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way, more concise, and efficient (about 10x on 1M points)

```
edges = np.linspace(0,points_range[0],x_steps+1), np.linspace(0,points_range[1],y_steps+1)
sums, _, _ = np.histogram2d(points[:,0], points[:,1], edges, weights=points[:,2])
counts, _, _ = np.histogram2d(points[:,0], points[:,1], edges)
means = np.where(counts>0, sums/counts, 0)
```

Comment: with x_steps = y_steps = 2, our methods have the same time (approximately) but on x_steps = y_steps = 30, your method is 60 times faster that's so cool

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going through your whole list for every tile, you can simply go trough all your points once, for each point check which tile it belongs to and update the corresponding mean by calculating the [cummulative average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Cumulative_average). This means, you go through your list exactly once.

```py
import numpy as np

points_range = np.array([2, 5, 1])
points = np.random.random((100, 3))  # points[:, i] will be referred as x, y, z for i in 0, 1, 2
points *= points_range

x_steps = 10  # We will divide the points x space in 10 columns
y_steps = 15  # We will divide the points y space in 15 rows
x_step_size = points_range[0] / x_steps
y_step_size = points_range[1] / y_steps

means = np.zeros((x_steps, y_steps))
# keep track of current number of points per tile for running average
points_per_tile = np.zeros_like(means)

for point in points:
    # check which tile the points belongs to
    tile_index_x = int(point[0] // x_step_size)
    tile_index_y = int(point[1] // y_step_size)
    # get current mean and current N
    current_mean = means[tile_index_x, tile_index_y]
    current_points = points_per_tile[tile_index_x, tile_index_y]
    # get updated mean
    updated_mean = (current_mean * current_points + point[2]) / (current_points + 1)
    # update values
    means[tile_index_x, tile_index_y] = updated_mean
    points_per_tile[tile_index_x, tile_index_y] += 1
```

SUGGESTED EDIT:

(with this edit, eficiency is similar to OP's solution on 1M points)

```
# keep track of current sum of points per tile for running average
sums = np.zeros((x_steps, y_steps))
# keep track of current number of points per tile for running average
counts = np.zeros((x_steps, y_steps))

for point in points:
    # check which tile the points belongs to
    tile_index_x = int(point[0] // x_step_size)
    tile_index_y = int(point[1] // y_step_size)
    # update
    sums[tile_index_x, tile_index_y] += point[2]
    counts[tile_index_x, tile_index_y] += 1

means = np.where(counts>0, sums/counts, 0)
```

Comment: Hi, I was implementing your method while you was putting the code lol. 
I prefer numpy because it parallel a lot of operations and I have a lot of points in my use case. Using time.time(), I measured the time taken by both versions.on 1000000 points (1million).
On this dataset, your method (with the exact same code) took 3.71 sec, while the one I posted took 0.81 sec. The ratio between both time depends on the machine processor I guess.

Comment: You are right. On my machine, the difference is not quite that big but even for 10 million points, your code is faster. The ineffectiveness of the algorithm (checking all points for each tile) is trumped by the efficiency of the numpy implementation.

Comment: rather than updating your mean at every new point, just  update the sum and counts, and get the means from them only at the very end, see edit...